# Retrofit Foundation Posts/Beams

Tags: framing, foundation, structural, crawlspace

Bought a new (old) place and our inspector pointed out beams/posts that need framing/structural straps in the crawlspace. Ballpark estimate I got from a foundation contractor (site unseen) was a $3,500 minimum, as he said they would have to put new posts in place with new structural straps.

Based on this photo, does it seem necessary? I can add these myself without replacing the posts, right? Obviously, correct installation for earthquake retrofit protection is the priority, but it seems overkill to pay to replace all the posts.

[image: inspector recommendation]

Comment: The inspector is the one who actually saw the posts up close, so I'd take his opinion over the guy who didn't.

Comment: Did the inspector say the posts need replacement or was that the contractor you talked to? From your post, it sounds like the inspector just said to add the straps. Also, jacking the house to replace the posts can cause cracking in the plaster or drywall. Does the contractor guarantee no cracks?